# Hiding IOS keyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch

In my app the user can edit some UItextViews, and on the press of a button he can hide the keyboard . I use this code:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

I use this code in two different UIViewcotnrollers. In one this code works, and hides the keyboard, on the other one it doesn't. Is there any reason? Am I missing something like a delegate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use: `[textView resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: you should consider adding an explanation of *why* or *how* your proposed solution solves the problem.

Comment: I had already tried this and it doesn't work, so the problem must be another one..

Comment: I'm sorry If I don't dive any explanation, but there are so many possibilities for the code [self.view endEditing:YES]; not to work that I wouldn't know